# Input dialog loop end early

Tags: java, while-loop, joptionpane

When the user enters nothing in an input dialog box it ends the loop below. I've debugged the code and name is indeed "" when the user enters nothing.

```
while(name == "" || name == null){
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name:");
    }
```

Also, When the window containing the input dialog is closed or cancelled, the program doesn't exit the loop.

Can anyone provide some insight for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't compare strings with `name == ""`. Use `"".equals(name)` or in your case even `name.isEmpty()` (available since Java 6).

`==` is used to compare references, not value of objects. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Change your code to:

```
while(name == null || name.isEmpty()){
    name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter you're name:");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Never use `==` to compare `String`s in `Java`.

Use the method `equals(String)`.

See the following [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference using "==" oder equals. Try also to use equalsIgnoreCase() to be sure

```
while(name == null || name.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter you're name:");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop comparing strings and start using the Apache Commons Lang [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) class.  It handles nulls nicely and is well tested.  You will want to use `StringUtils.isBlamk(name)` or `StringUtils.isEmpty(name)`

Answer (score 0):

The window closing not causing the program to exit the loop is because I needed to add a default close operation by calling JFrame's setDefaultCloseOperation with the parameter JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE. This terminates the JFrame and prevents it from running in the background after the window is closed.